# Using djcelery to scrape a website and populate django models

Tags: python, django, celery

I'm having trouble getting celery working with django. I want to use celery to scrape a website and update some django models every 20 minutes.

I created a task file in my app directory that has an update class:

```
class Update(PeriodicTask):
    run_every=datetime.timedelta(minutes=20)

    def run(self, **kwargs):
        #update models
```

The class correctly updates my modesl if I run it from the command line:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Update().run()
```

My celery config in setting.py looks like this:

```
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "database"
BROKER_HOST = 'localhost'
BROKER_PORT = 5672
BROKER_USER = 'Broker'
BROKER_PASSWORD = '*password*'
BROKER_VHOST = 'broker_vhost'
```

But when I run `manage.py celeryd -v 2` I get connection errors:

```
[2010-12-29 09:28:15,150: ERROR/MainProcess] CarrotListener: Connection Error: [Errno 111] Connection refused. Trying again in 10 seconds...
```

What am I missing?

**Update:**

I found [django-kombu](http://ask.github.com/celery/tutorials/otherqueues.html#django-database) which looked pretty good becuase it uses my existing database. I've installed django-kombu and kombu but now I get the following error when running `manage.py celeryd -v 2`.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 11, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "<webapp_path>/lib/python2.6/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 438, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "<webapp_path>/lib/python2.6/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 379, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "<webapp_path>/lib/python2.6/django/core/management/base.py", line 191, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "<webapp_path>/lib/python2.6/django/core/management/base.py", line 220, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "<webapp_path>/lib/python2.6/django_celery-2.1.4-py2.6.egg/djcelery/management/commands/celeryd.py", line 20, in handle
    worker.run(*args, **options)
  File "<webapp_path>/lib/python2.6/celery-2.1.4-py2.6.egg/celery/bin/celeryd.py", line 83, in run
    from celery.apps.worker import Worker
  File "<webapp_path>/lib/python2.6/celery-2.1.4-py2.6.egg/celery/apps/worker.py", line 15, in <module>
    from celery.task import discard_all
  File "<webapp_path>/lib/python2.6/celery-2.1.4-py2.6.egg/celery/task/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from celery.execute import apply_async
  File "<webapp_path>/lib/python2.6/celery-2.1.4-py2.6.egg/celery/execute/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from celery.result import AsyncResult, EagerResult
  File "<webapp_path>/lib/python2.6/celery-2.1.4-py2.6.egg/celery/result.py", line 9, in <module>
    from celery.backends import default_backend
  File "<webapp_path>/lib/python2.6/celery-2.1.4-py2.6.egg/celery/backends/__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
    default_backend = DefaultBackend()
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Comment: it says celery-2.1.4-py2.6.egg in your paste, but to use Kombu you need the development version of Celery (to become 2.2).  Install from git: http://github.com/ask/celery (or pip install -U http://github.com/ask/django-celery/tarball/master#egg=django-celery; pip install -U http://github.com/ask/celery/tarball/master#egg=celery;  in that order).

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't look like you have a broker installed/running (RabbitMQ?)

Comment: I was trying to get celery working with as little as possible :) I've got things working now with ghettoq. Thanks for pushing me in the right directory.

Comment: I'm getting the same error, also running GhettoQ. Is GhettoQ really this Ghetto?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and the problem was that I had the import path wrong.

Probably, you import task as

`from celery import task`.

While you should

`from celery.task import task`